# Basic addition loop c

Tags: c, stdio

I'm trying to write a code which adds a value - say X - to a user entered int, and continues to allow the user to add further int values to 'X+all previously entered int values' until a value of 21 or greater is reached - where the code exits the loop. I thought it would be a simple case of value=value+X but I'm going wrong somewhere...

```
void additionFunction()
{
     int j=0;
     int tot;

     //tot=cat.firstCard+cat.secondCard; is the actual tot value but for simplicity;

     tot=5;

     for(j=0; j+tot<22; j=j+tot)
     {
         printf("Enter next card\n");
         scanf("%d",&j);
     }
}
```

I know this is a very simple question but I'm stuck as to what else to try. It was originally implemented in a if,do,switch loop in the shortened form;

```
if(cat.firstCard!=11 && cat.secondCard!=11)
{
    do
    {
    switch(tot+j>=4 && tot+j<=8)
    {
        printf("Hit\nEnter next card\n");
        scanf("%d",&j);
        break;
    }
    switch(tot+j==9 && (cat.dealersCard==2 || (cat.dealersCard>=7 && cat.dealersCard<=11)))
    {
        printf("Hit\nEnter next card\n");
        scanf("%d",&j);
        break;
    }
    ...
    switch(tot+j>=17 && tot+j<=21)
    {
        printf("Stand\n");
        j=50;
        break;
    }
    switch(tot+j>21)
    {
        printf("Bust\n");
        j=50;
        break;
    }
    }while(j!=50);
}
else  //etc.
```

This method didn't work either. I know this is simple but I can't find the answer anywhere. It would be great if you could answer for the second case but any answer is appreciated!

**only use stdio.h, no global variables**

Comment: In the first code, you need to increment `tot`, not `j`, don't you?  Or you need to read into `tot` instead of `j`, but then the names, to the extent they are at all meaningful, are wrong.  You really need to check the return value from `scanf()` too, so you can spot that the user typed K (for King) instead of 9.

Comment: That's one weird way of writing `switch` :)

Comment: This is the way I was taught, what’s the usual way?

Comment: This is not the way I was taught. It was a late night...

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment `tot` rather than `j`.  I think it could be clearer like this:

```
void additionFunction(void)
{
    int tot = 5;

    while (tot < 22)
    {
        int j;
        printf("Enter next card\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &j) != 1)
            break;
        tot += j;
        printf("Read: %d - total = %d\n", j, tot);
     }
}
```

I've kept your variable names, but they could be improved (`tot` ⟶ `total`; `j` ⟶ `value`, perhaps).  I added the second `printf()` to identify what's going on better (but there's room to improve that, too, though a debugger could also be used to see the information).  I suspect you will need to do more work in the loop, or return a value from the function, but this is OK as an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are resetting j every time in the loop with user's input with this line - `scanf("%d",&j);`

This should fix it, by assigning input into another variable and add it to j.

```
 int j=0,input,tot=5;

 for(j=0; j+tot<22; j=j+input)
 {
     printf("j=%d tot=%d\n",j,tot);
     printf("Enter next card\n");
     scanf("%d",&input);
 }
```

Comment: You should really check the return value from `scanf()` before using it.  I'm not sure if the third variable is really necessary, but what you've written will basically work — assuming the input is valid.

Comment: right, this is definitely not the best and assuming input is valid, just addressing the problem from the original code... thanks for pointing it out.